# How to read xml from resource via xmlreader?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, resources, xmlreader

I want to read a file.xml in my project (I just want it packed in my .exe) using XmlReader.
It works when I read the file from the application folder, but i want to read it from the resources so I can give out my executable without additional files.

I tried different approaches but got none of them to work.
I use C# with WPF 3.0.

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried reading the resource as text? Are you sure you are including the resource in the exe file?

Comment: Thanks! I tried reading it with a StringReader and on top of the the xmlreader! Seems it cant read the EOF correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Add your xml file and mark it in the Properties as an "Embedded Resource". Load it with something like this:

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (Stream stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("LoadResourceTest.mydata.xml"))
        using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        { 
            ...
        }
```

My test program is LoadResourceText.exe thus the LoadResourceTest in this code.

Answer (score 2):

If your loading anything as a resource you have to use
[WPF Pack URI's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Some examples:

#### Absolute Path

```
"pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.xaml"
"pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml"
```

#### Relative Path

```
"/ResourceFile.xaml"
"/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml"
```